# PHP Use an API to select a specific value from a table by its ID

Tags: php, api

So this is the code I have so far, I'm leaving out the code I used to connect to the database since that's not important and isn't the problem.

```
 $id = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
 $sql_value = "SELECT value FROM table";
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value='[idk what to do here]' WHERE id='$id'");
```

so the $id selects the id from the url or API and the $sql_value selects the values from the table.

I want the value in the same row as the id specified to increment by 1

E.G.

```
id = 0, value = 0;
id = 1, value = 0;
id = 2, value = 0;
id = 3, value - 0;
```

If in the API I type: "id=2"
I want the PHP script to increment the corresponding "value" by 1

E.G.

```
id = 0, value = 0;
id = 1, value = 0;
id = 2, value = 1;
id = 3, value - 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET value=value+1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I was thinking that. I figured it wouldn't be as easy to just set it equal to itself + 1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `value` field is an `INT`. You can do that by:

```
"UPDATE table SET value=value+1 WHERE id='$id'"
```

But i strongly recommend you to take a look at [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and start to make prepared statements to handle the data. See more here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value is an int this will work:

```
UPDATE table SET value=value + 1 WHERE id='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE tablename t SET value = ( t.value+1 ) WHERE t.id = '$id'

Answer (score -1):

Do you want?

```
"UPDATE table SET value=value+1 WHERE id='$id'"???
```

Comment: What use would the first 2 be to me?

Comment: Only the last one is useful, even then that's been posted here like 50 times